# How do you Create Snowflake Procedure that returns Table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have seen so many example of Snowflake Procedures, but most I would really call functions. They return 1 number. Whenever I find one that supposedly returns a whole table of data, the example is super short and does not give enough information IMO to complete the instruction. I have a working query(Below). When I use Declared variables the query runs and a table is returned. However, once I drop it in the Stored Procedure framework, error after error is all I get. Usually Unexpected EOF or getting angry about my WITH statement. I have tried many things, Removing Language Declaration, changing the ";" all over the place, but nothing allow me to deploy much less run it. Based on this website, it seems easy enough, but no dice. Some higher level people at my work said Snowflake cannot do this type of work, but I find that hard to believe. How can it be so limiting? Any thought?
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/resultsets

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
    PROCEDURE TEST.TRANSACTIONS_GO(
        ParamServiceArea STRING 
        ,ParamLocation STRING 
        ,ParamDept STRING
        ,ParamStartDate STRING
        ,ParamEndDate STRING
        ,ParamCStartDate STRING
        ,ParamCEndDate STRING
        )
        RETURNS TABLE(ServAreaId STRING
                        ,ServAreaName STRING
                        ,LocId STRING)  
        LANGUAGE SQL
    AS

DECLARE results
RESULTSET DEFAULT (
;
WITH SAtag AS (
        SELECT sa.value AS SERV_AREA_ID
        FROM table(SPLIT_TO_TABLE($ParamServiceArea,',')) sa
)
, Loctag AS (
        SELECT CAST(l.value AS INT) AS LOC_ID
        FROM table(SPLIT_TO_TABLE($ParamLocation, ',')) l
)
, Deptag AS (
        SELECT CAST(d.value AS INT) AS DEPT_ID
        FROM table(SPLIT_TO_TABLE($ParamDept, ',')) d
)
,START_DATE AS (
SELECT CALENDAR_DATE AS START_DATE
FROM DIM_DATE 
WHERE CALENDAR_DATE = (SELECT DATE_CALCULATE($ParamCStartDate,$ParamStartDate))
), END_DATE AS (
SELECT CALENDAR_DATE AS END_DATE 
FROM DIM_DATE 
WHERE CALENDAR_DATE = (SELECT DATE_CALCULATE($ParamCEndDate,$ParamEndDate))
)
SELECT TDL.SERV_AREA_ID AS ServAreaId
            ,TDL.SERV_AREA_NAME AS ServAreaName
            ,TDL.LOC_ID AS LocId

        FROM TRANSACTIONS_MAIN TDL
        WHERE TDL.POST_DATE BETWEEN (SELECT START_DATE FROM START_DATE)
                        AND (SELECT END_DATE FROM END_DATE)
            AND TDL.SERV_AREA_ID In (select cast(SERV_AREA_ID as int) from SAtag)
            AND TDL.LOC_ID IN (
                    SELECT LOC_ID
                    FROM Loctag
                    )
            AND TDL.DEPT_ID IN (
                    SELECT DEPT_ID
                    FROM Deptag
                    )
        GROUP BY TDL.SERV_AREA_ID
            ,TDL.SERV_AREA_NAME
            ,TDL.LOC_ID
);
BEGIN
RETURN TABLE(RESULTSET);
END;
```

Comment: "When I use Declared variables the query runs and a table is returned.However, once I drop it in the Stored Procedure framework, error after error is all I get. " - what is the actual question? Please post a code you are expecting to be working and actual error message

Comment: This is it. The code "in" the stored procedure works. I can run it and it works with the with statements and the select statements. Really I just need any procedure that can return multiple column/rows I have not seen anything like that in Snowflake. All I did to my code was change the table names. Instead of creating a Procedure. Like I have here, I just declare/set the same parameters and of course remove all that Result set stuff which you do not need for a normal query. Then following all the instructions I added those Result sets to try to return. The real query has ~40 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, but assuming it is about returning a table and using parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST(Param INT)
RETURNS TABLE()  
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
BEGIN
 LET results RESULTSET := (SELECT :param AS col0, 1 AS col1, 'a' AS col2 
                           UNION ALL SELECT :param, 2, 'b');
 RETURN TABLE(results);

END;
```

Call:

```
CALL TEST(Param=>9);
```

Output - multiple columns and rows:

```
COL0    COL1    COL2
9   1   a
9   2   b
```

---

Parameters inside Snowflake Scripting SQL are accessed by using `:ParamDept` and not `$ParamDept`(session variable).

[Using a Variable in a SQL Statement (Binding)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables#using-a-variable-in-a-sql-statement-binding)

Comment: This worked, but how do you know when to use parameters with :Parameters vs $Parameters. Thank you so much. It looks like it was all in the Let results :=

Comment: @HolmesIV You do not use `$Parameters` inside Stored Procedures. It is a session variable - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables